# PHP - Allow Access to Page Only If Variable Exists in Url

Tags: php, html, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm sorry I couldn't come up with a more fitting title but here is what hope to achieve with **PHP**:

- I have a page with url ***www.foo[.]com/mypage***
- I only want that page or url to be accessible if it comes with `?user=$email` so if someone tries to visit the url without `?user=$email`, they get redirected somewhere else.
- How do I define that condition?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried using the following
- if (!$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET')

and 

$user = $_GET['user'];
if ($user == '') // if $user as a string is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @Edwin here is the solution for you question.

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['user']) && $_GET['user']!='' && $_GET['user']!=null) {
        header("Location: http://www.foo[.]com");
    } else {
        header("Location: http://www.foo[.]com/somepage");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this script !!!

```
if(!isset($_GET['user'])){
 header("location:./");
}
elseif(isset($_GET['user']) && $_GET['user']==''){
 header("location:./");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **mypage** Page at **TOP(Very First line)** just write following code

```
<?php
   if(!isset($_GET['user']) || (isset($_GET['user']) && $_GET['user'] == "") ){
       header("Location: http://www.foo[.]com");
   }
?>
```

Here I not only check if $_GET['user'] is available or not, I also check that there mus be some value pass to. Here you also no need to write else{} to continue.